# Can I configure IIS to display content from another *internal* IP?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, keyboard-video-mouse

I have three websites hosted on IIS, differentiated with host headers.  I used to manage the server locally or through RDP, but I've recently purchased an IP KVM that I'd like to utilize to help facilitate management out of Windows - plus, I'm changing offices.

The KVM is assigned an internal IP, because there's only one public address.  It uses HTTP, and I can't change the port.  Is there any way to create an IIS site that displays content from an internal IP (relative to the server's network)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the term is *Reverse Proxy*, and you need URL Rewriting and Application Request Routing installed.

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

> After you’ve created your site then open up URL Rewrite at the site level.
>
> Using the “Add Rule(s)…” template that is opened from the right-hand actions pane, create a new Reverse Proxy rule.

Add the inbound rule as the KVM server address. Maybe you need the outbound rule to rewrite any links the KVM serves up, if they aren't relative paths.